# How to return two values?

Tags: objective-c, methods

I'd like to return a Cartesian coordinate (x, y), as two `int`s. The only way I see is to create a class and return an instance of it.

How to return two values from a method in Objective C?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can only return one value from a function (just like C), but the value can be anything, including a struct.  And since you can return a struct by value, you can define a function like this (to borrow your example):

```
-(NSPoint)scalePoint:(NSPoint)pt by:(float)scale
{
    return NSMakePoint(pt.x*scale, pt.y*scale);
}
```

This is only really appropriate for small/simple structs.

If you want to return more than one new *object*, your function should take pointers to the object pointer, thus:

```
-(void)mungeFirst:(NSString**)stringOne andSecond:(NSString**)stringTwo
{
    *stringOne = [NSString stringWithString:@"foo"];
    *stringTwo = [NSString stringWithString:@"baz"];
}
```

Comment: And now with the introduction of Swift, you can return multiple arguments from functions using tuples. See [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you make an `NSArray` for this?

```
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:coorX, coorY, nil];
```

Comment: Using a dictionary / array as the return type is in _most_ cases bad style.

Answer (score 3):

You can either return one value directly and return another by reference, as shown in [gs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002745/can-you-return-two-arguments-in-objective-c/2002774#2002774), or create a struct type and return that. For example, Cocoa already includes a type to identify points on a 2D plane, [NSPoint](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSPoint).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you  to return an NSDictionary, inside Dictionary you can store and send any object type and any number of variables.

```
-(NSDictionary*)calculateWith:(id)arg
{
NSDictionary *urDictionary =@{@"key1":value1,@"Key2":value2,.....};
return  urDictionary;
}
```