# Swift return type clarification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4

I see a Swift function written as follows:

```
func calculation(imageRef: CGImage) -> (red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt]) {

 ...
 ...
}
```

I need to know what is the return type in the function above. I am unable to relate it to any of the known types & also what is its equivalent in Objective-C if any at all? What's the way to translate this function to Objective-C?

Comment: the return type (=[tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448)) in not representable in ObjC; in ObjC you could do (but not limited to) some ugly thing like that, for instance, `-(void)caluclationWithImageRef:(CGImage)imageRef red:(NSArray<NSNumber *> **)red green:(NSArray<NSNumber *> **)green blue:(NSArray<NSNumber *> **)blue { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a **tuple** that this function is returning.

A tuple can hold various types in one object, but unlike an array, you cannot append or remove objects to/from it.

[From Apple Developer Swift Guides:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329)

> Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values within a tuple can be of any type and don’t have to be of the same type as each other.

**Tuples don't exist in Objective-C.** [You can find more information about that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2002745/3151675)

Answer (score 1):

This called `Tuple`
[learn here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/tuple-in-swift-a9ddeb314c79)

it allows to group multiple values under single variable.

Objective c don't support tuple . in objc you have to use `dictionary` and you have to use key `red` , `green` and '`blue` with array as value

Answer (score 1):

```
func calculation(imageRef: CGImage) -> (red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt]) {

 ...
 ...
}
```

The above method returns **tuple** (A group of different values that you can use in Swift).

You can also return **tuple** without **named parameters**:

```
func calculation(imageRef: CGImage) -> ([UInt], [UInt],[UInt]) {

 ...
 ...
}
```

You can access the return values like this **(For un-named tuple parameters):**

```
let returnedTuple = calculation(imagRef)
print(returnedTuple.0) //Red
print(returnedTuple.1) //Green
print(returnedTuple.2) //Blue
```

or **(For named tuple parameters):**

```
let returnedTuple = calculation(imagRef)
print(returnedTuple.red) //Red
print(returnedTuple.green) //Green
print(returnedTuple.blue) //Blue
```

There is no equivalence of tuple in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

This method return a tuple

```
func calculation(imageRef: CGImage) -> (red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt]) {


    return ([],[],[])
}
```